# Align div vertically within nav element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to show the menu items in the (vertical) middle of the div?

I have watched more than 10 videos on centering and looked at about 20 online "tutorials". Everyone uses jQuery/Bootstrap and the built in classes. I have recreated every effect by hand, but I can't get the menu items div to come down to the middle.

https://jsfiddle.net/2zwxL14q/

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <h1 style="height: 75px; width: 200px; background: #f00;">
      <a href="/">
        LOGO
      </a>
    </h1>
    <div id="navelements">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  background-color: #13293d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav h1 {
  float: left;
}

#navelements ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#navelements ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#navelements ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the `nav` this styles

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
```

then you `nav` will be totally in the middle as you expected

```css
nav {
  background-color: #13293d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav h1 {
  float: left;
}

#navelements ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#navelements ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#navelements ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
    <h1 style="height: 75px; width: 200px; background: #f00;">
      <a href="/">
        LOGO
      </a>
    </h1>
    <div id="navelements">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this?

- https://jsfiddle.net/2zwxL14q/2/

**StackOverflow live example:**

```css
nav {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #13293d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav h1 {
  float: left;
}

#navelements ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#navelements ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#navelements ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <h1 style="height: 75px; width: 200px; background: #f00; position: absolute;">
      <a href="/">
        LOGO
      </a>
    </h1>
    <div id="navelements">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```